# Writing to .text section of a user process from kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-memory

I'm writing a kernel space component for a research project which requires me to intercept and checkpoint a user space process at different points in its execution (specific instructions.)  For various reasons I cannot modify the user-space program or ptrace that process.

To accomplish this goal I'm attempting to insert an breakpoint (INT 3 instruction) in the user-space process at the point I need to checkpoint it, and then intercept the SIGTRAP in kernel space.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to properly modify the read-only text section of the user-space code from the kernel space of that process.  I'm currently attempting to use the `get_user_pages` API to force the pages writable, and modify them, but the text data doesn't seem to change.  The relevant portions of the code I'm attempting to use are below.  `user_addr` is the user-space address to insert a breakpoint at `(unsigned long)`; `page` is a `struct page *`.

```
char *addr;
unsigned long aligned_user_addr = user_addr & ~((unsigned long)PAGE_SIZE - 1);

down_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
rc = get_user_pages(current, current->mm, aligned_user_addr, 
                    1, 1, 1, &page, &vma);
up_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
BUG_ON(rc != 1);

addr = kmap(page);
BUG_ON(!addr);

offs = user_addr % PAGE_SIZE;

/* NOTE: INT3_INSTR is defined to be 0xCC */
addr[offs] = INT3_INSTR;
BUG_ON(addr[offs] != INT3_INSTR); // Assertion fails

set_page_dirty(page);
kunmap(page);
page_cache_release(page);
```

I'm hoping someone with more kernel knowledge and experience will be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong, or the proper way to go about accomplishing my task.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my issue was actually with C sign extension.  `INT3_INSTR` was defined as:

```
#define INT3_INSTR 0xCC
```

Which makes it an integer, and the line:

```
BUG_ON(addr[offs] != INT3_INSTR);
```

evaluated `addr[offs]` to be a `signed char`.  In c when a `signed char` is compared to an `int` its type is elevated to that of `int`, and since its signed it will be signed extended if its MSB is 1.  As 0xCC's MSB is always 1 the comparison always evaluated to:

```
BUG_ON(0xFFFFFFCC != 0xCC);
```

Which evaluated as false.  Changing `addr` to a `unsigned char *` resolves the issue. and then the above code works.